# How to quote \" (slash double-quote) in a string literal?

Tags: c#, string, literals

This is probably a really simple question but I can't seem to get my head around it. I need to have a string that contains `\"` without it seeing it as an escape character. I tried using `@` but it won't work. The only other way I thought of doing this would be to use `\u0022` but don't want to unless I can help it.

Desired string - `string s = "\"\""; // Obviously this doesn't work!`

Desired console output - `\"\"`

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
string s = "\\\"\\\"";
```

You have to escape your backslashes too.

Mike

Answer (score 7):

You can use the literal, but you need to double-up quotes.

```
   string s = @"\""\""";
```

Answer (score 5):

In verbatim string literals (`@"..."`) a `"` in the string value is encoded as `""`, which happens to also be the *only* escape sequence in verbatim strings.

```
@"\""Happy coding!\"""     // => \"Happy coding!\"

"\\\"Happy coding!\\\""    // => \"Happy coding!\"
```

Note that in the 2nd case (not a verbatim string literal), a `\` is required before the `\` *and* the `"` to escape them and prevent their normal meanings.

See the [C# string reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to escape backslashes too... so something like `"\\\"\\\""` should work, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Use this string:

```
string s = "\\\"\\\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine( "\\\"\\\"" );
```

Just put a `\` before each character that needs to be printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = @"\""\""";
```

DblQuote characters will escape a second dblquote character

Though for better readability I would go with:

```
const String DOUBLEQUOTE = """";
const String BACKSLASH = @"\";

String s = BACKSLASH + DOUBLEQUITE + BACKSLASH + DOUBLEQUOTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a verbatim string (a string starting with `@""`) to escape double quotes you use double quotes, e.g. `@"Please press ""Ok""."`. If you want to do it with verbatim strings then you would do something like `@"\"""` (that's 3 double quotes on the end there).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
string s = "something'\\\'";
```

Use a single '' rather then "" in string to do the same.